# Unsupported file format of sitemap - Google

Tags: google-search-console, sitemap

I'm having an issue where I'm submitting my sitemap, too bad I keep this omitted error:

> Unsupported file format
>
> Your Sitemap does not appear to be in a supported format. Please ensure it meets our Sitemap guidelines and resubmit.

I followed the sitemap guidelines and error reporting types:

- [Creating Sitemaps](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=183668).
- [Sitemap errors](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=35738).

This is what my sitemap looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
  <url>
    <loc>http://mywebsite.com/home</loc>
    <changefreq>weekly</changefreq>
    <priority>0.2</priority>
  </url>
  <url>
    <loc>http://mywebsite.com/feedback</loc>
    <changefreq>weekly</changefreq>
    <priority>0.2</priority>
  </url>
  <url>
    <loc>http://mywebsite.com/search</loc>
    <changefreq>weekly</changefreq>
    <priority>0.2</priority>
  </url>
</urlset>
```

It seems fine enough, so I re-submitted it and then it returned the same error, that my sitemap is unsupported.

The sitemap has a application header of `text/xml` if changed to `application/xml`, it still won't work. What is causing this error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. You can validate your sitemap here (if it is not **too** big):  [[1]](http://sitemapxml.net/sitemap-validator.php), [[2]](http://www.w3.org/2001/03/webdata/xsv), [[3]](http://www.webmasterwebtools.com/sitemap-validation/index.php) or use any other [tool](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=sitemap+validator).
2. I do not see the required `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>` part here -- did you forgot to copy it .. or you do not have it at all? The first link you are referring to has it in the example.
3. Maybe it is worth adding FULL "header/definition" of the `<urlset>` -- I have it this way everywhere and never saw any rejections/validation issues:

Your sitemap.xml could be looking like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9 http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd">
  <url>
    <loc>http://mywebsite.com/home</loc>
    <changefreq>weekly</changefreq>
    <priority>0.2</priority>
  </url>
  <url>
    <loc>http://mywebsite.com/feedback</loc>
    <changefreq>weekly</changefreq>
    <priority>0.2</priority>
  </url>
  <url>
    <loc>http://mywebsite.com/search</loc>
    <changefreq>weekly</changefreq>
    <priority>0.2</priority>
  </url>
</urlset>
```

Comment: Just done everything you labelled down, I didn't forget the `<?xml` tag. I ran a validation test, both `sitemap` and `sitemap index` ran success without any errors. Still getting the same error.

Comment: Hmm.. I just tired the recommended-by-myself validator .. and it validated even non-existed document. Please ignore it and use **another** tool. I just tested my own sitemap [here](http://sitemapxml.net/sitemap-validator.php), [here](http://www.w3.org/2001/03/webdata/xsv) and [here](http://www.webmasterwebtools.com/sitemap-validation/index.php) -- all fine. Please use your REAL sitemap (with **real** URLs). Right now I see no reasons why it it should be rejected.

Comment: Well .. then I guess you need to just wait a day or so .. and resubmit your sitemap again via WebMaster Tools. At the same time you can add this line into your **robots.txt** -- this will tell everyone who reads and understands robots.txt where to find your sitemap: `Sitemap: http://YOUR_WEBSITE/sitemap.xml`

Comment: Okay, I shall do that then. :-) Could you remove the URL please, I have reasons not to keep the link on the page. Thanks.

Comment: If you open an xml file, in a browser, it does not show the `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>`... OP had not forgotten to include it... you need to download the file and open it in a text editor in order to see it.

Answer (score 1):

In our case, the issue was that we did not include a question mark in the XML declaration on the first line. We wrote it like this:

```xml
<xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8">
```

When we should have written it like this instead:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

Obviously, it would have been nice if Google's error was more specific.