# Sitemap can be read, but has errors: Unsupported file format

Tags: google-search-console, sitemap, xml-sitemap

Google Search Console is showing the following error:

[image]

> Sitemap can be read, but has errors
>
> Unsupported file format

I tried validating the sitemap [here](https://www.xml-sitemaps.com/validate-xml-sitemap.html?op=validate-xml-sitemap&go=1&sitemapurl=shopless.co.nz%2Fsitemap.xml&submit=Validate%20Sitemap), and it shows me the following error:

[image]

> Incorrect http header content-type: "text/html" (expected:
> "application/xml")

But don't understand how to fix it? My [sitemap](https://shopless.co.nz/sitemap.xml) is an xml file.

Comment: Your sitemap is missing the `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>` and `xmlns` that are required at the top of it.  See [Unsupported file format of sitemap - Google](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/16412/unsupported-file-format-of-sitemap-google) for details.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller: My sitemap contains both of those elements and attributes. It does not show the first one if you open the xml file in a browser, but if you save the page and open it in an editor you will see that those elements are there.